# dbt: check what packages are installed

Tags: dbt

Is there a way to check what packages are installed? I would expect something like `dbt list packages`?

The context is:

- Until I run `dbt deps` the content of `packages.yml` gives me nothing. And there are some situations when the models could be triggered without running `dbt deps`
- I would like to check the packages in runtime

I searched over google and `dbt --help` but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment about packages.yml because to include any packages you must first add them to this list. If you are using imported packages then you should ALWAYS run `dbt deps` as a first step.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths basically I want to check what the packages are REALLY installed in runtime, not the ones that SHOULD be installed

Comment: There is no way to do that I am aware of, and I don't understand why you would need to do that if you're running dbt in the intended manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I had the opportunity to work with packages closely and I published an article [The Practical Guide to Utilizing DBT Packages for Data Transformation](https://dev.to/freshbooks/the-practical-guide-to-utilizing-dbt-packages-for-data-transformation-4138#verify-packages-are-installed) which explains `dbt packages` and its underhood

Here is the quote:

To verify that a package is installed in your dbt project, you can check the `packages.yml` file and run the `dbt deps` command.

1. Check the `packages.yml` file: This file lists all of the packages that are installed in your dbt project. Look for the name of the package you want to verify. If it is listed in the packages list, then it is installed.
2. Run the `dbt deps` command:

   1. This command will show you a list of all of the packages that are installed in your dbt project. Look for the name of the package you want to verify. If it is listed, then it is installed.
   2. In the root dbt project dir, you observe a new dir `dbt_modules/` which contains the compiled packages that are ready to be used. **NOTE**: dir `dbt_modules/` has to be added to `.gitignore`.

```
>>> tree -L 1 .
.
├── data
├── dbt_modules
├── dbt_project.yml
├── macros
├── models
├── packages
├── packages.yml
├── profiles.yml
├── snapshots
└── target
```

If your `packages.yml` file contains package that is not installed then you would not be able to run any dbt command:

```
>>> dbt list
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  dbt found 1 package(s) specified in packages.yml, but only 0 package(s) installed in dbt_modules. Run dbt deps to install package dependencies.
```

So this is our guarantee that in runtime we would not have any issues related to the package installation.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no `dbt list packages` command; there is no `--list` option for `dbt deps`; packages are not listed in `dbt debug`; installed packages are not listed in `manifest.json`; nor is there another officially supported analog of `pip list` to determine all of the currently-installed packages in your runtime.

You should [open an issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues) for this!

Your current options (v1.3.0) are:

1. Run `dbt clean` and `dbt deps` before any other dbt command, to ensure your installed dependencies match what is in your `packages.yml` file.
2. Run `dbt compile` and inspect `manifest.json` to ensure it has the macro(s) and/or model(s) you need from a package (note that `dbt compile` will fail if packages are listed in `packages.yml` and not installed).
3. Inspect your project's `dbt_packages` subdirectory. Each installed package will have its own directory; if that package has any dependencies, they will be nested under subsequent `dbt_packages` directories.

`dbt clean` and `dbt deps` are pretty fast, so the cost of (1) is low, and you don't have to manage the logic/complexity of various bad states if you go that route. But I think you should absolutely open an issue for this!

Comment: I suggest that the reason dbt doesn't provide any of the things you list in the first paragraph is that the intended usage of dbt is option 1) i.e. always run dbt deps as a first step. If this is done then I can't imagine a scenario where it would be necessary to programatically query the "installed" packages. Can you describe a use case where this would be necessary, e.g. some kind of deployment where it's impossible to run dbt deps?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a `packages.yml` file in your repo that contains all the packages that are installed via `dbt deps`.

Following the `dbt deps`, a directory called `/dbt_modules` (by default, can be changed in your `dbt_project.yml`) will appear in your repo (it is included, also by default, in your `.gitignore` file to avoid duplicating the source code for the package).

Comment: Please, read my initial message and thought about `packages.yml`: `Until I run dbt deps the content of packages.yml gives me nothing. And there are some situations when the models could be triggered without running dbt deps`

Comment: packages.yml is the “list” you are looking for, there is no more. Once you run ‘dbt deps’, packages are installed, and it is in that moment that a ‘dbt run’ will run any of the models included in those installed packages.

Comment: `packages.yml` is the list of the libs that SHOULD be installed. but it's not necessary will be installed. Imagine, you have `package1` in the above-mentioned file. For some reason, you didn't run `dbt deps`. So it means that you cannot rely on the content of this file.  What I'm looking for - is the way to check what libs are already installed and are ready to be used.